# Checksum of all the database in MySQL innodb

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, checksum

I was looking for a way to get a checksum of the whole current database. I found that : [MySQL documentation : CHECKSUM TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/checksum-table.html). Sounds nearly what I'm looking for, but it is only one table and I would like to execute this on the whole database.

I tryied the following in order to apply to all tables, but it doesn't work (I think it's a wrong usage of `CHECKSUM TABLE`).

```
CHECKSUM TABLE (
    SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = database()
);
```

Is there any way to checksum the whole database ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the checksumming?

Comment: Without any modifications on the MySQL **innodb**, trying to check if there's something changed in my database.

Comment: Sounds like you need better control over user access.  Alas, there is no simple way to check for changes, not even a timestamp on a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-table-checksum.html --

> pt-table-checksum performs an online replication consistency check by
>   executing checksum queries on the master, which produces different
>   results on replicas that are inconsistent with the master. The
>   optional DSN specifies the master host. The tool’s exit status is
>   nonzero if any differences are found, or if any warnings or errors
>   occur.
>
> The following command will connect to the replication master on
>   localhost, checksum every table, and report the results on every
>   detected replica

Comment: I was looking for a solution to do it in one request with an already open connection. There's no way to do it with a simple query ?

Comment: Why does it have to be a simple query?  This is a very disk-intensive task, since it needs to read all the data from all the tables.  If you are trying to snapshot the checksum for an instant in time, then it must also act like an "transaction", else the data will be a 'moving target'.  This adds more complexity.

Comment: You're right, maybe i'm not approching this in the right way.